# Error on accessing data in a list of tuples F#

Tags: xamarin, model-view-controller, f#, elmish

Cannot assign a position to **View.Pin** from a list of tuples (There are 300 tuples in the real program), please comment how to fix it.

**Error : The type 'a list' is not compatible with the type 'View Element'**

```
let tokyo = Position(35.652832, 139.839478)

// create sample tuples
let t1 = ("35", 48.856, 2.3522)
let t2 = ("32", 51.5074, -0.1278)
let t3 = ("25", 50.9513, 1.8587)

// create sample list
let lst = [ t1; t2; t3 ]

let map =
    View.Map
        (hasZoomEnabled = true, hasScrollEnabled = true,
         pins = [ lst |> List.map (fun (_, a, b) -> View.Pin(Position(a, b), label = "Dummy", pinType = PinType.Place)) ],
         requestedRegion = MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(tokyo, Distance.FromKilometers(300.)))
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We can't help you fix a type error if we don't know what the type of any of the functions involved are.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.map%5B%27t%2C%27u%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D"

To my surprise, F# is an awesome functional language to handle large data set in only a few lines of codes.

```
 let view (model : Model) dispatch =

        // A list of 300 tuples
        let jpnDatas = jsonData.jpnData

        let pins =
            jpnDatas
            |> List.map (fun (_, a, _, _, b, c) -> View.Pin(Position(b, c), label = a, pinType = PinType.Place))

        let tokyo = Position(35.652832, 139.839478)

        let map =
            View.Map
                (hasZoomEnabled = true, hasScrollEnabled = true,
                 pins = [ for pin in pins do yield pin ],
                 requestedRegion = MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(tokyo, Distance.FromKilometers(300.)))
```